# Combining lists into one list which has cheapest ones among them

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting, data-structures

I have two lists which contain the price of the hotels from different sources, however, I want to combine these two lists and create a final one which will only include the cheapest results between this two? Can anyone tell me what will be the best way to achieve this? I was thinking to use cross join, however I feel it will be a lot of computation time.

Hotel Collection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   public class Program
    {

       static List<hotel> vendor1Hotels = new List<hotel>{new hotel
        {
            room = new Room
            {
                roomId = 2,
                totalPrice = 200
            },
            hotelId = 2,
            vendorId = 1
        } };

      static  List<hotel> vendor2Hotels = new List<hotel>{new hotel
        {
            room = new Room
            {
                roomId = 2,
                totalPrice = 300
            },
            hotelId = 2,
            vendorId = 2
        } };

        static List<hotel> Hotels { get; set; } = new List<hotel>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var hotel1 in vendor1Hotels)
            {
                foreach (var hotel2 in vendor2Hotels)
                {
                    if(hotel1.hotelId == hotel2.hotelId)
                    {
                     if(hotel1.room.totalPrice < hotel2.room.totalPrice)
                        {
                            Hotels.Add(hotel1);
                        }else
                        {
                            Hotels.Add(hotel2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }

   public class hotel
    {

       public Room room { get; set; }

        public int vendorId { get; set; }

        public int hotelId { get; set; }

    }

    public class Room
    {

        public int roomId { get; set; }

        public double totalPrice { get; set; }

    }
}
```

above will be added to the output collection **Hotels**

I want to compare the totalprice property of the room class in each individual hotel of the collections **Vendor1Hotels** and **Vendor2Hotels** if the hotel id is equal and add it to **Hotels** collection else no need to compare just need to add that hotel to the final collection **Hotels**.

Comment: "only include the cheapest" so your final list will contain only 2 prices ?

Comment: Create a new list. Find cheapest ones from first list and add them to the new list. Find cheapest one from the another list and add them to the new list.

Comment: criteria of "cheapest results" is unclear, confusing and a subject of removal question

Comment: You are right, cross join is bad. Use either full outer join or `Concat` + `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 1):

you can group hotel's rooms by hotelId, roomId, vendorId and then just take cheapest from each group, like this

```
var ret = response1.Vendor1Hotels.Union(response2.Vendor2Hotels)
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.hotelId, x.vendorId, x.room.roomId})
            .Select(x=>x.OrderBy(r=>r.room.totalPrice).First())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: your grouping is done on hotelid vendorid and roomid. it should only be on hotelid because he wants the best price from all the vendors at the specific hotel.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dictionary of hotels for each list, which would map a hotel to price. Then go over both lists and compare the prices. Note that using dictionary will decrease the complexity of the algorithm from O(N)*O(M) to O(N)+O(M), where N,M are number of elements in each list. This is because dictionary has search complexity of O(1). You can actually get similar result with single dictionary, but this will result in a bit more complex code.

Answer (score 0):

Think I am a but late but here is how I would do it.

```
 var result = vendor2Hotels.Union(vendor1Hotels)
                           .GroupBy(hotel => hotel.hotelId)
                           .Select(hotelgroup => 
                                   hotelgroup.OrderBy(hotel => hotel.room.totalPrice).First())
                           .ToList();
```